# Printing multiple html2canvas with multiple getElementById in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to convert my html to pdf. But my elements are on different html page with different IDs.

For example:

*index.html*

```
<html>
   <body>
      <header id="header">Header</header>
   </body>
</html>
app.component.html

<div id="content">Content</div>
app.component.ts

data = document.getElementById('content');
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); 
});
```

But this prints only 'content' data and not header data. I want both IDs i.e. header and content to be printed on same pdf using html2canvas.
        Kindly help.